# How to randomize json

Tags: php, json, random

I have a randquotes.json file

```
{
    "author": "William Shakespeare",
    "quotes": "A brave flea is a flea that can dare to get its breakfast on the lips of a lion."
},
{
    "author": "Winston Churchill",
    "quotes": "We live with what we get, but we bring life to what we give."
},
{
    "author": "Wolfgang von Gothe",
    "quotes": "Knowledge is not enough, we must practice it. Intention is not enough, we must do it."
}
```

Then I want "author" and "quotes" to be generated randomly with php

How?
thanks for help

Comment: Do you mean you want to pick one of these quotes at random?

Comment: Yes, how can i make it?

Comment: Can you provide valid JSON first

Comment: You don't: JSON is a string representation of actual things, so randomize _those things_ and then convert that to JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually have valid a JSON string...

1. Convert the json to a PHP datatype using `json_decode()`
2. find out how large the array is
3. generate a random number between 0 and array size
4. Return that array occurance, I did that as a json string again using `json_encode()`

```
$json_string = '
[
    {
        "author": "William Shakespeare",
        "quotes": "A brave flea is a flea that can dare to get its breakfast on the lips of a lion."
    },
    {
        "author": "Winston Churchill",
        "quotes": "We live with what we get, but we bring life to what we give."
    },
    {
        "author": "Wolfgang von Gothe",
        "quotes": "Knowledge is not enough, we must practice it. Intention is not enough, we must do it."
    }
]';

$arr = json_decode($json_string);

// How big is the array
$max = count($arr) -1;

$rand_idx = rand(0, $max);
echo json_encode($arr[$rand_idx]);
```